# Is there a tool to convert between VS2005, VS2008 and VS2010 solutions and projects (not only .NET)?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2005, projects-and-solutions, converters

I want to convert projects and solutions between VS2005, VS2008 and VS2010. 
For Example from VS2010 to Vs2005 or 2008 to VS2010, from VS2008 to Vs2005. Is there that tool exist?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is project converter for versions 2005-2012 on [Codeplex](http://vsprojectconverter.codeplex.com). There is another project converter for versions 2002-2008 on [Sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/vspc/).