# visual studio 2010 solution viewer or converter?

Tags: visual-studio

my computer only has visual studio 2005. there are some 2010 projects that I need to read through, I don't need to run them, just need to read through them and learn.

originally I wanted to convert 2010 project to 2005, but the best converter out there don't support 2010 projects. I thought about doing it manually, but the .vcxproj file are vastly different.

then I thought about downloading a solution viewer for 2010 or something. microsoft did that with their office files so people with older office could still view the docx and stuff, but they didn't do this for visual studio projects.

how can I get to read the project solution?

Comment: Visual Studio 10 Express Edition? (It's free)

Comment: Have you thought about building a solution in 2005 using the files?

Comment: Similar question: [Is there a tool to convert between VS2005, VS2008 and VS2010 solutions and projects (not only .NET)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9600027/is-there-a-tool-to-convert-between-vs2005-vs2008-and-vs2010-solutions-and-proje)

Comment: ^ I already tried that page, didn't work, that's why I am looking for a viewer

Comment: Define "didn't work". Maybe there's a fix?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried downloading [Visual Studio 2012 Express](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng#products/visual-studio-express-products)?

There is also [SharpDevelop](http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SD/Default.aspx).

Comment: I have to say, MS are bolloxing up their web sites trying to make them 'Windows 8' surface look and feel.

Comment: downloading and installing the express takes too much time, I just need a quick viewer. plus the express will expire and needs continuous renewal, and once the next one comes out the old one becomes garbage.

Comment: "downloading and installing the express takes too much time" - huh?